# How to add Slides in Powerpoint by Access VBA keeping it minimized only

Tags: ms-access, vba, powerpoint, minimized

I am creating a powerpoint file and adding slides into it programmatically through Access-VBA and it is working fine till now. 
But Now, the client wants that the ppt should be invisible or minimized during generation only. Just after activating the ppt object, I set it minimized, but then also, during 'Slides.Add', it again pops up, so I need to minimize it again. The issue is that this causes cursor focus move to ppt instead of document he is working on.
So, is there any way, I could completely keep it minimized or do this generation work in background and only open it once its done?
The code I am using is:

```
Dim shpGraph As Object, Shpcnt As Integer, FndGraph As Boolean
Dim lRowCnt, lColCnt, lValue As Long, CGFF_FldCnt As Integer
Dim OPwrPnt As Object, OpwrPresent As Object, OpwrSlide As Object
Set OPwrPnt = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
Set OpwrPresent = OPwrPnt.Presentations.Add(WithWindow:=msoFalse)
Set OpwrSlide = OpwrPresent.Slides.Add(slideCounter, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitle)
OPwrPnt.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
slideCounter = slideCounter + 1
lheight = OPwrPnt.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2
lwidth = OPwrPnt.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 1
LLeft = 0
lTop = OPwrPnt.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 4
Set shpGraph = OpwrPresent.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=LLeft, _
                Top:=lTop, Width:=lwidth, Height:=lheight, _
               ClassName:="MSGraph.Chart", Link:=0).OLEFormat.Object
```

I have written the code to minimize the windowstate just before and after Add function, but still it pops up just for a fraction of second, hence moving the cursor focus from any document they are working to the ppt, which they dont want.
So how can I keep it completely minimized?

Comment: Best recommendation would be to pre-populate the powerpoint.  This may be difficult if you aren't aware of how many slides will be needed, but if you are, then simply add the correct number of slides, minimize the document, then iterate through the slides by index in a loop

Comment: @RGA Thanks for the reply, but thats what I am already doing, this code snippet is just its minimized version. But they want that right after clicking the Generate button, the ppt generation should happen in background and should not popup anytime before completing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the powerpoint object without a window (assuming you never use `Select` or any `Active...` references

```
Set oPPTPres = oPPTApp.Presentations.add(WithWindow:=msoFalse)
```

then, adding slides to that presentation should be conducted completely invisibly.  After that, I believe you will have to just save, close, and re-open the presentation (with the `WithWindow` property set to true) to view it

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me simple code snippet of what you want to tell. That would be very helpful.

Comment: I tried this code, but its giving me error on the second line that there is no active presentation: Set OpwrPresent = OPwrPnt.Presentations.Add(WithWindow:=msoFalse)
                        Set OpwrPresent = OPwrPnt.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(slideCounter, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitle)

Comment: @HemantSisodia thats because you can't use an ActivePresentation (as stated in my answer).  You need two seperate objects, one for the presenation, one for the slide.  so `Set OpwrPres = OPwrPnt.Presentations.Add(WithWindow:=msoFalse)`  then `Set OpwrSlide = OpwrPres.slides.Add(...)`

Comment: Please see my edited code, I am getting errors at ActivePresentation line call as well as the last one for ShpGraph due to these changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HemantSisodia as I've stated twice now, you **cannot** use "ActivePresentation" or "ActiveSlide" or anything involving the word "Active" if you open it in a windowless mode.  You need to instead use the presentation object (as defined `OpwrPres` in my previous comment) and the slide object (defined as `OpwrSlide`)

Comment: But I am not using ActivePresentation in the last line and still I am getting the error as 'Object doesn't support this property.'

Comment: @HemantSisodia I don't think you need the `.OLEFormat.Object` after making the `.AddOLEObject(...)` call.  Pretty certain that is the cause of your new error (not one caused by the changes i suggested)

Comment: No, I removed '.OLEFormat.Object' but still getting the same error.

Comment: @HemantSisodia you are using the wrong variable.  A Presentation does not contain shapes.  A Slide does.  Change `OpwrPresent` to `OpwrSlide`

Comment: Thanks, it is solving my problem, need to make changes at so many places though, but still I am getting what I wanted. Thanks a lot.